# For which (g,q) does there exist a supersingular curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, finite-fields

We say a curve over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$ is supersingular if it's Frobenius eigenvalues (on $H^1(X,\mathbb Z_\ell)$) are of the form $q^{1/2}\alpha$ for $\alpha$ a root of unity.

As far as I know, the question: "For which pairs $(g,q)$ does there exist a supersingular curve of genus $g$ over $\mathbb F_q$" is open. Partial results that I know are:

1. Over characteristic $2$, every genus occurs: [van der Geer, van der Vlugt](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9404007).
2. Genus $4$ in arbitrary characteristic is known: https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08095
3. The Hermitian curve $y^q + y = x^{q+1}$ is supersingular for $q = p^n$. [slide 20](https://www.pims.math.ca/files/SlidesPries1.pdf).
4. [The Supersingularity of Hurwitz Curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.01582) proves for a specific farmily of $(g,q)$.
5. Theorem 1.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.04598) lists, for $4\leq g\leq 11$, some congruence conditions on $p$ for which there exist supersingular curves.

I am sure I have missed a few but I are there are any large families that I have missed? What is the state of the art today?